# How to edit a tag wiki

Tags: support, badges, tag-wiki

[image]

I have more than 700 reputation points as I remember I have already unlocked the tag wiki edit privilege. But still, I don't know what it means and how to do that.

How can I do tag wiki edits? A screenshot would be nice.

Comment: If you hover over a tag anywhere you see one, it will tell you what to do.  There is a link there that either says "View Tag" or "Help Us Edit This Wiki."  At the View Tag page, there is a link that says "Improve tag info."

Comment: I think you're getting "community wiki" and "tag wiki" confused. You only need 100 reputation to edit *community* wikis, but you need 20000 to freely edit *tag* wikis.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can choose *Improve tag info* from your selected tag main page (just click at a particular tag from either the home page, or your watched tags list at the right sidebar):

[image]

Then you'll be presented with the tag-wiki info edit page:

[image]

You provide your edits, and submit. Then you'll wait if your edits pass the review.

If these passed, you'll receive the badge after a while (6-8 something).

Answer (score 11):

You can edit a tag wiki using the following URL template

```
https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/some-tag-name
```

For example, if you want to edit the tag wiki of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), you can go to

https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/javascript

---

I recently learned that if you have 5 (or more) pending suggested tag wiki edits, you can't edit any more tag wikis - the option simply disappears - until some of your outstanding suggested edits are approved. The mechanism is the same as suggested edits of regular posts, so no surprises there.

The weird part is that edits of tag wiki and tag wiki excerpts are counted as separate edits *even when they are of the same tag*. So for example, if you decide to improve the tag wiki and the corresponding excerpt of 3 tags, it counts as 6 suggested edits, thus exceeds the limit and you cannot edit any more tag wikis until at least 2 of your edits are approved. The edits are approved separately; presumably, wiki and excerpt edits are reviewed separately.

You can also get 2 rep points for each of tag wiki and excerpt edits as shown in the image below.

[image: rep history]

Comment: Are there two separate counts / limits?

Comment: @Peter, You can [scheme to get 6 edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333076/282094), but if you have 5 (or 6) pending you are [blocked from improving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297490/282094) (re-editing your pending edits, prior to approval). [Suggested Edits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/282094) and [*why are edits blocked* FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/282094).