# Unable to edit wiki tag

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Currently I'm trying to edit a wiki tag [`[docc]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docc) for a recently released framework of Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/docc.

However, I do not see an edit button(<kbd>Improve tag info</kbd>) on the tag's page, screenshot attached below.

---

### [image]

- My guess is it's either because there is only 1 question under the tag, or it's because the tag was created recently.

---

- A related question can be found here: [How to tag wiki edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382297/how-to-tag-wiki-edit)

However as a popular comment suggested under [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382298/12861639):

> why is there no edit options for few tags? what does that mean? Please explain.

Comment: there is an edit pending. It needs approving, so you have to wait to find someone with enough reputation to accept the edit made

Comment: @nbk Proposed excerpt was copied from Apple's website, and lacked usage guidance. Such proposals should be rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UI for editing tag info provides functionality to create *both* the excerpt (that is visible when hovering over the tag) and the wiki at the same time:

[image]

Because the two are linked, when there is a pending [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29254459) for the except, you cannot suggest a revision to the wiki. Therefore, you must wait for the pending excerpt review task to complete.