# Why can't some tag wikis be edited?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I've edited a few tag wikis before, but wanted to make an edit to the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag. However, when I click 'Improve tag info' I don't have the option to edit the tag. The text box to edit, which comes up for other tags, doesn't appear for [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

If it matters, I have a silver badge in the tag (~550 score). I'm also on ~12k reputation. I know with 20k+ reputation you can edit tags without review.

The only related thing I can find when looking is a comment on this answer for [How to tag wiki edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382298/9607863) asking about why some tag wikis can't be edited, but there was no response.

- What's stopping me from editing this tag?
- Do I need a gold badge or 20k+ reputation to edit this tag?

Comment: Is it limited if the suggested edit queue is full, maybe? I see close to 500 pending tasks

Comment: There is also an edit [pending](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29746658) on that tag already, to remove a single period... Perhaps that's why.

Comment: It seems to have a pending edit and you can only suggest edits, since you are no [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) yet.

Comment: @CertainPerformance But then why can I see the edit box for other tags, but not the [tag:swift] tag?

Comment: @JeanneDark The problem is that there is no edit box to edit the tag, not relating to making suggested edits. Could be because of the pending edit, though. (I'll add this info to question)

Comment: Yes, it will be due to the pending edit, @George . Something that has a pending edit cannot have further edits sent by users that aren't "trusted". It's nothing to do with it being a tag; the same is true for questions and answers (or anything else you can edit).

Comment: @Larnu Ok, that's useful to know. I thought I'd ask this question, since this specific problem doesn't appear to have been asked before. I'll be happy to accept an answer that you write

Comment: Then the solution is easy: do 40 suggested edit review on the spot. This is the most easy queue. Right after it won't be full, so you will be able to make your edit.

Comment: @peterh The problem as said be Larnu is that there is already an edit waiting in the queue. The problem is the text editor not showing up, not that it won't let me submit an edit. I have done a few reviews anyways.